# REDCap Longitudinal Survey Not Displaying Correctly via Email

Tags: longitudinal, redcap

I have a REDCap project intended to do the following tasks:

1. Allow an individual to register for an event.
2. Allow a registered individual to cancel their registration if necessary.
3. Capture contact information of individuals who were unable to register for the event due to capacity to add them to a waitlist.
4. Allow registered individuals to answer a pre-event survey when they arrive to the event.
5. Allow registered individuals to answer an immediate post-event survey upon completion of the event.
6. Allow registered individuals to answer a delayed post-event survey 90 days after completion of the event.

I have the project set up as a longitudinal project with four events: Registration, Pre-Event, Post-Event, Post-Event 90 days. I have six instruments: Intake, Registration, Waitlist, Cancel Registration, Pre-Event Questionnaire, Post-Event Questionnaire. Event designation grid is below.

[Event designation grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1QT.png)

Intake, Registration, Waitlist, and Cancel Registration are available 30 days prior to the event. Upon registration, the registered individual will receive an email with a personalized link to cancel their registration and to their personal pre-event questionnaire (which is not active at the time that the individual receives the email). Pre-event questionnaire and post-event questionnaire should become available on the day of the event if the patient has not canceled their registration. Once the individual has completed the pre-event questionnaire, they should receive access to the post-event questionnaires.

Currently, the link to the pre-event questionnaire is not working and I get an error message stating that the survey has not been set up correctly.

[Survey not set up correctly error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97STC.png)

The only way I am able to get the pre-event questionnaire to display is to include it in the "Registration" event. I have also not been able to get the logic to hide the questionnaire until the day of the event using Survey Queue.

Any insight into getting the pre-event questionnaire to (1) display correctly via the email link and (2) hide the questionnaire until a specific date would be appreciated.